# React-redux error when webpack: SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: webpack, redux, react-router, reactjs

Here is a strange problem, here is the code:

```
...
const PrivateRoute = ({status, component: Component, ...rest}) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={ props => (
      status ?
        (<Component {...props}/>) :
        (<Redirect to="/login"/>)
    )}/>
)

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    status: state.user.status
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute)
```

The error when doing webpack -d -w:

```
ERROR in ./public/javascripts/src/admin/components/PrivateRoute.jsx
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (4:53)

  2 | import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
  3 | 
> 4 | const PrivateRoute = ({status, component: Component, ...rest}) => (
    |                                                      ^
  5 |   <Route {...rest} render={ props => (
  6 |     status ?
  7 |       (<Component {...props}/>) :
```

The code is just follow the tutorial over [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow).
However, the code blow also uses the '...' in Route {...rest}. When I remove the first '...', the second and third doesn't produce the error. Why does that happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is experimental syntax. You need to include [object-rest-spread](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/) plugin in your babel config. Or use a preset that includes this plugin. For example [`stage-3`](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=false&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-3&targets=Node-8&browsers=&builtIns=true&debug=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBAHjAvDAFAb1AWwA7gKZhQBcMASiAK5R4BOANDAHTPY0jYQC-AlEgHwwAPOSq0YaZo1bsuMatERoAjJwD0fIA)

As of this

> When I remove the first '...', the second and third doesn't produce the error. Why does that happen?

`<Route {...rest}` is handled by jsx plugin included into `react` preset. [Repl](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=false&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact&targets=Node-8&browsers=&builtIns=true&debug=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBAHjAvDAFABwE4jRAlEgPhgB4AlEAVygFMMYBvAOmc2wgF8YbpF6BGdgHoCQA).

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Update you `.eslintrc.js`, set `experimentalObjectRestSpread` to `ecmaFeatures` as `true`.

```
parserOptions: {
  ecmaVersion: 7,
  sourceType: 'module',
  ecmaFeatures: {
    jsx: true,
    experimentalObjectRestSpread: true
  }
}
```

See https://eslint.org/docs/rules/rest-spread-spacing